# Help using Set Builder Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently learned about set-builder notation, but I'm having trouble understanding it. How can I write $P_3$, the inner product space of polynomials of degree at most 3, in set builder notation?

Comment: totally unclear what you are asking

Comment: Are you asking about vector spaces of polynomials of bounded degree?

Comment: I think you mean the polynomial space of degree at most $3$: $\mathbf{R}[X]_{\leqslant 3}=\{a+bX+cX^2+dX^3 \mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbf{R}\}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Apologies. I meant inner product space of polynomials of degree at most 3.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question and included the name for the kind of notation you're interested in

Comment: @NirvanaGuha has the comment by rae306 answered your question? Seems like it should. If not, could you clarify what more you want to see?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Two ways are as follows:

$$\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R\}$$
$$\{p(x)\in\mathbb R[x]|\deg(p)\leq 3\}$$